# Slim Framework 4 - Using $this when not in object (Medoo Framework) PHP

Tags: php, slim, medoo

I have updated my project based on Slim Framework to Slim 4 today. I'm working with the Medoo (database framework) here.

https://medoo.in/api/collaboration
Here the Slim integration is explained:

```
use Medoo\Medoo;

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['database'] = function () {
    return new Medoo([
        'database_type' => 'mysql',
        'database_name' => 'name',
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'your_username',
        'password' => 'your_password'
    ]); 
};
```

The Query looks like:

```
$datas = $this->database->select("accounts", "*");
```

The error message I have received since the update is the following:

> Got error 'PHP message: Slim Application Error:\nType: Error\nCode:
>   0\nMessage: Using $this when not in object

Have any of you had the problem? I have tried everything that I have in experience. I can't get any further here

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. What `$this` means to you?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Yes, I know what the error message means. But I doesn't found a workaround what works in this case.

Comment: Create a service class and let the DIC (PHI-DI) inject the database as dependency (via constructor injection).